# Laravel Spark : how to choose which Plan is offered in trial?

Tags: laravel, laravel-spark

I'm using Spark with Teams. My app has 3 plans : Free, Pro and Agency. When an user signs up, he is placed in a Trial mode for 30 days, on the Free plan.

Instead, I'd like to offer the Pro (paid) plan to my users during their trial period. After this period, IF they didn't sign up for a paid plan, I'd like them to "fallback" to the free plan.

Do you have any idea how to achieve this ?

The Free plan is added using Spark::freeTeamPlan() The other ones with Spark::teamPlan()

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

You need to collect a credit card from the user to subscribe to a paid plan - even on a trial basis.

```
Spark::plan('Basic', 'team-basic')
->price(10)
->trialDays(10)
->features([
    'Five Team Members',
    'Feature 2',
    'Feature 3',
]);
```

[Spark Documentation](https://spark.laravel.com/docs/9.0/billing#requiring-credit-cards-up-front)

If you wish to offer a free trial with your paid pro plan features, you can essentially offer the same features to users on trial as those on the paid pro plan. You may need to create multiple free plans and distinguish between them in order to distinguish between the free plan and the pro trial.

Would recommend reading the Laravel Cashier docs, they form the underlying library used for Laravel Spark subscriptions ([here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/billing)).